# C#.Net Interview create an object from a class

Tags: c#, oop

Having just finished the first part of my schooling I'm looking for work. I went to an interview for a C#.net developer. During the interview I was asked to create a class with two properties. Then in a asp.net form create an object from that class. So I created a class with a constructor that took two strings, setting the properties of the object. In the asp.net page I added two text boxes and a button. In the button's click method I put in the line `Class whatever = new Class(textbox1.text, textbox2.text)`

So after I finish I look at the gentlemen that are interviewing me and wonder why they are looking at me like I'm crazy. So I ask, "You don't think that will work?" They replied, "Run it and we'll see". Ok, so I ran the program, entered some text into the text boxes and clicked the button. Guess what, nothing happened lol. At which point I said, "If you want, I can output the object to some labels or something if you want." They said as they were looking at me like I've done something wrong, "No, just put a break point on this line and run the program again." So we run the program again, the break point shows that the object was created with the text. Then I hear "Hmmm, that worked." At which point I tuned to them and said, "Are you guys messing with me or did you really think that that wouldn't work?" They replied that what I was was just a really old way to create an object. Are there other ways to create an objects? What was I supposed to do? I was taught in all of my programming classes that to create an object from a class this is the right way to do it. Does anyone have any idea what these guys wanted from me? Maybe at the next interview I won't get stumped like that again.

Thanks for any help,

Craig

Comment: I'll recommend this for [programmers.stackexchange.com](programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: what is programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You created on object on the server.  Where nobody can hear it scream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a constructor is the ONLY way to instantiate an object. There are different ways to get to it, but ultimately the constructor is ALWAYS called. You instantiated it fine.

This raises two questions for me:

1. Did you misunderstand the question and relay it incorrectly here?
2. Are the interviewers really dumb?

If it's number 1, bad luck. 
If it's number 2, if I were you, I wouldn't take that job if you're offered it!

A few ways to construct an object:

```
// Default constructor:
MyClass instance = new MyClass();

// overloaded constructor:
MyClass instance = new MyClass(val1, val2, valN);

// object initialiser constructor:
MyClass instance = new MyClass
{
    Val1 = val1,
    Val2 = val2
};

// runtime with given type
Type myClassType = typeof(MyClass); // this would be more dynamic (unknown at design time)
MyClass instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClassType) as MyClass;

// runtime with reflection
Type myClassType = typeof(MyClass);
ConstructorInfo cstr = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
MyClass instance = cstr.Invoke(new object[]()) as MyClass;
```

Comment: Thanks, some new ones for me to research, The first 3 I know about, the last ones I'll need to research.

Answer (score 1):

Objects can be created in different ways but I think they should have given you chance to create the object in the number of ways you know before judging you

Here is one

```
SomeClass whatever = new SomeClass
{
   property1 = textbox1.Text,
   property2 = textbox2.Text
}
```

Or

```
SomeClass whatever = new SomeClass();
whatever.property1 = textbox1.Text;
whatever.property2 = textbox2.Text;
```

The first example is more recent

Comment: but you still need SomeClass whatever = new SomeClass(); that's where these two were having a problem.

Comment: How about: `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SomeClass));`

Comment: The first example is syntactic sugar: the parameterless constructor is still being called. @Craig I somehow find it hard to believe that "create an object" was the whole interview question. Surely there was more to it than that?

Comment: @codesparkle. Sounds to me like a simple OO question to test the interviewee's understanding of what an "object" is. I don't think that's so unbelievable. That said, I too am suspicious of the "whole question" given the interpreted feedback from the OP.

Comment: pretty much they were working with a database and were creating new entries for different production parts. It was a brake and suspension company. They handed me a cable with a bunch of connectors on it and asked me to make a representation of it.

Comment: I even wrote a new project just for the interview using my own database. All completely new code to me. Learned alot about linq and data access though.